# WebAudio FDN Lossless Prototype unstable when using individual feedback gains

Tags: javascript, algorithm, delay, web-audio-api, feedback

I'm trying to build an FDN Reverberator in WebAudio by following [this article](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/FDN_Reverberation.html).

There is a simplified implementation of a [Householder FDN](https://www.dsprelated.com/josimages_new/pasp/img762.png) which uses a common feedback gain for all delays and seems pretty stable.

However, when I try to implement the more general case that is mixed by a [matrix](https://www.dsprelated.com/josimages_new/pasp/img746.png) I cannot seem to make it stable.

I have inlined most of the code to narrow down the issue, and put it in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p18kovo5/143/).

**EDIT:** Warning, high volume in the unstable case.

The difference comes down to this:

```
var feedback = context.createGain();
feedback.gain.value = gainValue;

for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    this.delays[i].connect(feedback);
    feedback.connect(this.delays[i]);
}
```

Compared to:

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(var o=0; o<n; o++) {
        var feedback = context.createGain();
        feedback.gain.value = gainValue;

        this.delays[i].connect(feedback);
        feedback.connect(this.delays[o]);   
    }
}
```

When I use a common feedback GainNode for all delays, it works fine. When I create individual feedback GainNodes for all delays, using the same gainValue, it becomes unstable.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Clarification from [the article](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/FDN_Reverberation.html).

> As mentioned in §3.4, an "ideal" late reverberation impulse response should resemble exponentially decaying noise [314]. It is therefore useful when designing a reverberator to start with an infinite reverberation time (the "lossless case") and work on making the reverberator a good "noise generator". Such a starting point is [often] referred to as a lossless prototype [153,430]. Once smooth noise is heard in the impulse response of the lossless prototype, one can then work on obtaining the desired reverberation time in each frequency band (as will be discussed in §3.7.4 below).

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you could try dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hey, thanks. Migrated the question from there to here :)

Answer (score 0):

The gain nodes add volume to each other. If you use multiple gain nodes you need to split their value by the number of active gain nodes.

So if you have 10 gain nodes plaing simultaneosly your volume for the gain node would be value / 10 (number of active gain nodes). You need to edit the value of gain nodes before as well to the new value. So best to store all Gain nodes in an array and loop over it.

I didn't try it but I think it should work. It is physically totally nonesense, because if you have ten people crying in the same room the db-Meter is still as loud as if one would cry. Try to think of gain nodes more in a Mathematical way that they add up the signal to each other.

Your Reverb is dope by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried every possible combination of altering the gains that I could think of, from small to large amounts and in different places, and it's still unstable. From what I understand there are positive and negative gains that are meant to cancel each other out. I can for example make it build up and crash by lowering one of the gains from 1 to 0.9. I agree that there is something that needs to compensate for the additional gain lines, I just can't figure out what and how.

Comment: I just checked for five minutes and if i divde through 9 it gets pretty stable,...

Comment: you need to scatter the gain nodes of the delay lines randomly so the metallic noise dissappears. If you read more about fdn matrix reverbration than you need to randomly scatter the matrices.

Comment: Modulating the feedback delays is one way of hiding metallic ringing if that is a problem. Since it is not (IMO) a problem in my stable case (the one with a common feedback gain), I don't think it is the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In Code it means:

```
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(var o=0; o<n; o++) {
            var feedback = context.createGain();
            feedback.gain.value = gainValue/9;

            this.delays[i].connect(feedback);
            feedback.connect(this.delays[o]);   
        }
    }
```

I may reuse this code someday right??? If I set n to 30 I get kind of a cymball sound.

Comment: Well, this introduces loss which is undesirable. I will update the question with a clarification. Regarding permission of use, I will put this on GitHub with a proper licence once we get it working :)

Comment: it is lossless. We don't cut sounds we just tweak the overall volume so it doesn't squeek. The sound it generates sounds somewhat like a matrix reverb. So what are you searching for?

Comment: What I want is for the case of multiple individual feedback gains to sound like the case with one common feedback gain, an (almost) infinite reverberation. These cases are toggled by the checkbox in the JSFiddle. When I run my original code it quickly builds up a ringing resonance and crashes. When I run your code it quickly decays to 0, i.e. is not lossless anymore.

Comment: Basically what you just said. I want to convert the simplified implementation of the Householder FDN to a general matrix FDN.